# Fastest way of computing a row mode on binary entries dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, optimization

I am trying to optimise a piece code which find the **row** mode(s) of a dataframe with boolean entries. Here row mode is not the mode per column, but the row vector(s) repeated the most.

I have a working way of doing:

```py
some_binary_entry_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(10,300) < 0.5)
pd.util.hash_pandas_object(some_binary_entry_dataframe, index=False).mode()
```

But I am finding it quick slow for the task, ~100ms for a dataframe shaped `20x300`. It has turned into the bottleneck of my code. How can this be optimised in pandas or numpy?

Edit 1:
A more detailed example of what I want the code to achieve, I am trying to filter out the rows that do not match the majority (mode)

```py
entries = pd.np.zeros((3,3))
entries[1:,0] = 1
# entries = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
__df = pd.DataFrame(entries.astype(bool))
row_hashes = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(__df, index=False)
mask = row_hashes.isin(row_hashes.mode())
__df = __df[mask]
# __df.values.astype(int) = [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

After profiling the CPU is mostly busy with the call to `pd.util.hash_pandas_object` hence why I am trying to optimise it.

Edit 2:
I have replaced the hashing by `__df.apply(lambda x : hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)` with a nice speed-up.

Comment: I could not get `pd.util.hash_pandas_object(some_binary_entry_dataframe, index=False).mode()` to work. Can you add sample dataframe and expected o/p?

Comment: @Divakar I have added a line to generate some test data. I may add a relevant example of input/output later.

Answer (score 1):

This more "manual" method seems to be much faster:

```py
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

def binary_mode_mask_counter(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    cols = a.shape[1]
    # Convert every row into a big integer value
    h = np.array([sum(int(v) << i for i, v in enumerate(r)) for r in a], dtype=object)
    # Count frequencies
    c = Counter(h)
    # Get most frequent values
    _, max_count = c.most_common(1)[0]
    ms = [m for m, n in c.items() if n == max_count]
    # Return mask
    return np.isin(h, ms)
```

Comparison:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Original method
def binary_mode_mask_pd(a):
    h = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(a, index=False)
    m = h.mode()
    return h.isin(m)

# Benchmark
np.random.seed(0)
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 300) < 0.5)
%timeit binary_mode_mask_counter(a)
# 2 ms ± 44.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit binary_mode_mask_pd(a)
# 81.8 ms ± 1.49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```